# lodash solution for input value ={}

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I have a form with some input fields, and I need to get a JSON from server, then take input default values form that JSON object, but sometimes the object might be empty due to network problems, and at such times the I get error that the value can not be null,
I need a way to handle that with **Lodash**, can anybody please help me?
and please tell me how do I pass it to value={}

the example of not using Lodash is below, I wanna get rid of all &&s in my code

```
<Input value={userProfile && userProfile.result.job} onChange={() => setJob(...userProfile.result.job)}  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla JS has [conditional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` syntax:

```js
const userProfile = null

console.log(userProfile?.result?.job)
```

If conditional chaining cannot be supported, you can use lodash's `_.get()`:

```js
const userProfile = null

console.log(_.get(userProfile, 'result.job'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```